# hibernate two column unique index cannot update values

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

So I am trying to add a **unique constraint** that uses two column. I added the unique constraint in db and I have following Java code

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "test_table",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
        columnNames = {
            "other_table_id",
            "sort_order"
        },
        name = "my_unique_constraint")
)
class SomeTable {

    private String label;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "other_table_id", nullable = false)
    private OtherTable otherTable;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sort_order", nullable = false)
    private int sortOrder;
}
```

When I modify the sorting for this table and update the record I get

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
 Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'my_unique_constraint'
```

How do I implement `@UniqueConstraint` such that I don't get this kind of error.

Comment: Can you supply your modification code?

Comment: Do you mean full code?

Comment: I wonder how the update is done. Do you really do the update or actually trying to insert the second record.

Comment: I call hibernate saveOrUpdate to update the entity

Comment: And both are update.. data are already inserted using hibernate save method.

Comment: `saveOrUpdate()` does the UPDATE if @Id property is set on entity and INSERT if it is `null`. Your configuration seem fine. I belive the issue is in the entity modification code.

Comment: When saveOrUpdate is called entity have id on them. So I believe they are updating the entity. If I remove the unique constraint everything is working fine but of course duplicate value can be added.

Comment: where is the @Id ?

Comment: omitted for brevity

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because your uniqueConstraints aren't separated.

So my approach is to separate the two constraints:

```
@Table(
    name = "test_table",
    uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "other_table_id"),
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "sort_order")
    },
        name = "my_unique_constraint")
)
```

Comment: I believe this will create two unique constraint and we cannot have same sort_order twice in a table. I want to make unique constraint such that other_table_id doesn't have duplicate sort_order.